# How I can find out the name of Query?

Tags: rest-api, ruby, ruby-on-rails

Currently I am working on a project that I am to connect my company's application to salesforce account.

Now, in order to know about salesforce, I am trying a tutorial of quick start.

And according to the description, it seems I can update the data in salesforce with post request but I don't know how.

First of all, I don't even know the name of the query I want to change and don't know how to check it.

I already tried the request below and I got the response, but there are too many choices that I can't even find the right query I ought to use.

```
curl https://something---trsdfssf.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v52.0/sobjects/ -H "Authorization: Bearer 00D1s00asdfasegdasdf78608pwb\!AQQasefasdfasdagsrvPxmJPasdfasdfasd8Wm2ZVORySSKIJbA5NX2nLiaZ.baVadfasK" -H 'X-PrettyPrint:1'
```

So, I want to know...
how to find out the name of Object in salesforce and use it in query so that I can't do something to change the data in it.

Please kindly help me.
Thank you so much.

Comment: That depends on your business requirement. What do you need exactly? If you're trying to work with Account, then the endpoint is https://something---trsdfssf.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v52.0/sobjects/Account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't guess what object you need - you'll have to talk to your company's Salesforce Administrator to figure that out as it's relevant to your project's specifics..

There's [standard and custom objects](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/data_modeling/objects_intro). Standard objects are provided objects by Salesforce - ex. Account, Contact, etc. Your company can create custom objects that they've named (ex. Project__c, Engagement__c, etc) in addition to those provided objects.

In terms of what endpoint, once you get the objects you need there's documentation on [creating a record](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_create.htm), [updating a record](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_update_fields.htm), and [querying the records](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_query.htm) you want.

Generally, assuming you know the object's name you'd do the following:

1. Query the record using [SOQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql.htm) and the endpoint above (criteria being based on your work/project).
2. Update the record using the fields/values returned from step 1 and using the endpoint identified in the docs `something---trsdfssf.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v52.0/sobjects/{objectName}/{recordId}`

Comment: thank you so much for your comment.
I found the object's names in editing objects.
and I could use it for rest api. thank you.